# Remove Scrollbar from ComboBox JavaFX

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, javafx-2

I want to remove the scrollbar from the `combobox` and hence increase the height of the `combobox` when it is open. Meaning, i want to see all the items without scrolling.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, that is not a good idea. What will happen if the popup exceeds the size of the Stage? You will be in not state to check everything present inside it.

Comment: It will never be, that is assured. Just 3 records down there and I don't want the user to scroll down. Combobox input won't change

Comment: Have you tried to set combobox.setVisibleRowCount()

Comment: worked like a charm! Mr. life saver! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want scrolling and the list options will remain few in number and relatively constant, you might actually want the **ChoiceBox** UI element. It has relatively the same function as the ComboBox without the scrolling capability.

> ... 
>   choice boxes, the UI controls that provide support for quickly selecting between a few options.

Check out the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/choice-box.htm) on how to use them -- it's very similar to the ComboBox.

Comment: Thanks for that, but there is no way to use cellFactory. Would i be able to achieve what i desire i.e. adding color to background of each item in this case?

Comment: Ahh, for that, I'm not sure.. ChoiceBox only allows String cells. Sorry I didn't gather that from the question. I wonder if you could just include a string of html.. create a rectangle of color `colorChoice`.. whether or not your app would render that, I'm not sure.